# D3 blocks: How to change order of files

Tags: d3.js, block

I am using [blocks](https://bl.ocks.org/) to create and share my d3 snippets. When I have more than one file, for example [this block](https://bl.ocks.org/akshayKhot/0d920ab89f646e7bdbcd58601581478c), the `data.tsv` the file appears second. It's a huge file, so if someone wants to see the javascript code he has to scroll all the way down.

My question is, is there any way to change the order in which files are displayed in blocks? It seems to not follow Github gist's alphabetical order as `index.html` appears before `data.tsv`. Or do I have to create just one `index.html` file and put all my javascript and CSS code in it? like most of the blocks do.

Answer (score 0):

`index.html` is always listed first, then the other files are listed alphabetically. Something I'll prepend an `_` to interesting files, like `_script.js` to force them to show up first.